# Get actual folder path

Tags: c++, directory

How I can get actual folder path where my program is without my exe file name in C++?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737996/directory-of-running-program-on-linux/738024 - there are similar dupes for windows.

Comment: Yep, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory/875264#875264

Comment: Heh, seems to be your answer Neil :)

Comment: Yup, and on some systems (especially embedded) the question doesn't even make sense. C++ doesn't assume executables are files, nor does it assume a lot about the existance of (sub)directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will give you the application path:

```
::GetModuleFileName(NULL, szAppPath, MAX_PATH);
```

Now to extract the folder, you need to find the last backslash:

```
char szApplicationPath[MAX_PATH] = "";
::GetModuleFileName(NULL, szApplicationPath, MAX_PATH);

//Get the folder part
CString strApplicationFolder;
strApplicationFolder = szApplicationPath;
strApplicationFolder = strApplicationFolder.Left(strApplicationFolder.ReverseFind("\\"));
```