# C, open files relative to executable's path?

Tags: java, c, linux, path, getresource

I want to fix an old C program (got the source) that uses relative paths to load data files, expecting the executable is called from the directory where it is placed, such as `LoadEx("./dataFile", dataFile);` Of course calling the program from another directory fails since the `dataFile` cannot be loaded.

How can I modify the C program to load `dataFiles` relative to the executable's directory?

**EDIT:**
My original question turned inapplicable and so is a duplicate to at least:
 - [How do I find the location of the executable in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c)
 - [How to open a file with it's relative path in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988002/how-to-open-a-file-with-its-relative-path-in-linux)
 - [Finding current executable's path without /proc/self/exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe/1024937#1024937)

Comment: The Java method you listed does not read resources relative to the executing Java class, but rather, relative to its classpath.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I misunderstood how `ClassLoader` in Java works. Being so, my original question turns inapplicable... Then I guess there is no other way but finding the absolute path with `proc` or setting the absolute path via configuration, in which case my question becomes a duplicate from the other one

Comment: The argv[0] parameter to the main function in the C code should have the complete file name and path of the executable.  Assuming you have a main function and haven't wiped your args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you want `readlink("/proc/self/exe")`?  This is the way one finds the executable's path on linux.

The only other way is pull the PATH from the environment with `getenv()` and walk the PATH directories looking for a match for argv[0].  The first option is much easier.

Or write a script to initiate the program after first doing a `which` on the executable and passing the result in as a command line argument or some such hack.

Comment: Thanks Duck. I guess I find it quite ugly having to depend on so much detail of a specific OS instead of being able to use a more standard solution. If I wanted to run it on more OSes I would have to check `proc` or `argv[0]` or `$PATH` or `GetModuleFileName` as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c   But probably this is the way how it's done?

Comment: filesystems are OS dependent. Not all OSes even have filesystems!

Comment: What can you do, it's an imperfect world.  If it makes it any easier to accept this is probably what Java is doing beneath the covers too.

Comment: @ObscureRobot of course, but, in my opinion, a language could easily provide a library for this for standard OSes

Comment: The C language was designed for implementing OSes, so the very idea of a "standard" OS is nonsensical. Kernighan and Ritchie never expected Unix to become as popular as it did (nor did Linus, when he started out on Linux).