# Locating a resource file in the same directory

Tags: python, relative-path, absolute-path

I am building an application that needs access to a resource in the same folder (It needs the xsd file to validate the input file).

How can I reach this xsd file reliably?

To elaborate:

1. I need to be able to call the executable:

   ```
   cd not/the/directory/of/the/program
   path/to/program -c config.xml
   ```
2. What is the path to use here?

   ```
   subprocess.Popen("xmllint --noout --schema ?/?/config.xsd " + configfilename)
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)

Comment: You should be able to get the current working dir with `os.getcwd()`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the zeroth command-line argument your program gets. It's usually the name of the program, and might also include a path to the program. Combine that with the current directory. Then use [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) or some equivalent of it to get rid of symbolic links. However, I think there are still some corner cases where this approach might fail.

You didn't specify /the programming language/ or operating system you are using. If you're writing a bash script, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/11451509

For Python, see [How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)

If the operating system is Linux, you could also go through the `/proc` pseudo filesystem, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/738024/11451509